# ng-init in uib-carousel -> height becomes 0px

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

After adding ng-init with images and unique id inside uib-carousel everything is equal to 0px (images, div's inside uib-carousel).

[Here is plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gx40RVMJYMjltA8PqT3Y?p=preview)

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" ng-init="slides = [{id: 1, image: 'https://placekitten.com/g/200/300'}, {id: 2, image: 'https://dgshow.org/files/2014/09/320px-Macaca_nigra_self-portrait_rotated_and_cropped-200x300.jpg'}]" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
```

Comment: does it work when you have it as $scope.slides ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38687846/6712896)

You just need to replace :

```
index="slide.id"
```

By :

```
index="$index"
```

Comment: or you can start your id from 0 instead of 1 in slides, seems like the index starts looking from 0